# Required attribute not working for select tag by onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to alert a value when a user clicks the submit button. I gave the "required" attribute to both select tag but it is not working.

I want to alert a value when a user submits a button. Can anyone tell where i went wrong?

Code:-

```js
function openWindow() {
  var OR = document.getElementById("request").value;
  var SZ = document.getElementById("sites").value;
  var ORSZ = OR + SZ;
  alert(ORSZ); 
}
```

```html
  
<select id="request" class="dropdownbox" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="ip">approve</option>
    <option value="url">reject</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="sites" class="dropdownbox" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="cp">Account</option>
    <option value="sm">Demat</option>
    
  </select>

 <input type="button" onclick="openWindow()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Relevant code belongs directly into your question, so please edit it accordingly.

Comment: You are not actually submitting your form, so of course the validation is not performed either.

Comment: `select required` works in normal form submission, that's why it's not working here (also it's not supported in opera)

Comment: edited the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on `required` attribute of `<select>`(because it's only work when form submits normally, and not supported in Opera anyhow).

You can make it happening like below:-

***Example:-***

```js
function openWindow() {
  var OR = document.getElementById("request").value;
  var SZ = document.getElementById("sites").value;
  if(OR =='' || SZ ==''){
  alert('Please select values from both select-box'); return false;
  }else{
    var ORSZ = OR + SZ;
    alert(ORSZ);
   }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="request" class="dropdownbox">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="ip">approve</option>
    <option value="url">reject</option>
  </select>

  <select id="sites" class="dropdownbox">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="cp">Account</option>
    <option value="sm">Demat</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="openWindow()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1mydje82/1/

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
  var required = false;
  $('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === '')
      required = true;
  });

  $('input[value="Submit"]').attr('disabled', required);
});

$('input[value="Submit"]').click(function(){
  var OR = $("#request").val();
  var SZ = $("#sites").val();
  var ORSZ = OR + SZ;
  alert(ORSZ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="request" class="dropdownbox" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="ip">approve</option>
    <option value="url">reject</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="sites" class="dropdownbox">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="cp">Account</option>
    <option value="sm">Demat</option>
    
  </select>

 <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've used `jQuery`. Initially your **Submit** `button` will be `disabled`.

Once you select both the `drodown` with values then only **Submit** `button` will be enabled.

Hope this will help you.